# How can I allow SSH and SMTP only using IPTables?

Tags: security, iptables, ip, firewall

I've got a raspberry pi set up to send me periodic emails. As it's connected to the internet 24/7, I need IPTables set up properly.

I want to allow incoming SSH and allow emails to send out on port 587 via SMTP. I've came up with this IPTables script, is it correct? If not, can you tell me why. Thanks.

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 587 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A iptables rule like this works fine

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:156]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT  -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT  -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
COMMIT
```

The first rule DROP by default all incoming connection
the second DROP by default all forwarding
the third ACCEPT the output,why accept?Is not too unsafe imho to make open the output connections,close it can make the firewall configuration a little difficult.

```
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Accept the connection with state RELATED and established state

the rest is easy

```
    -A INPUT  -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT  -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
    -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
    COMMIT
```

accept 22 tcp,accept 587 tcp and forbid all the other connections,
you can save on file and then do

```
iptables-restore < firewall.file
```

And check it with `nmap -sS` your host

Comment: +1 about default ACCEPT for OUTPUT and RELATED/ESTABLISHED INPUT. Else, you have to think about accepting DNS requests and so on. +1 also about ACCEPT any lo INPUT.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not comfortable working with the `iptables` commands you could use `UFW` instead. UFW stands for Uncomplicated FireWall and is a way easier tool to use than iptables.

Install `ufw` on your Raspbery Pi with:

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
```

After you've installed ufw you can set up the defaults with:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming && sudo ufw default deny outgoing
```

This will deny everything trying to connect in and will deny all outgoing requests as well, which is good if you want to be a bit more restrictive.

To allow `ssh` **in** do:

```
sudo ufw allow in 22
```

To allow `587` **out** do:

```
sudo ufw allow out 587
```

For more info check in `man ufw` which has a lot more examples and explains things very well.